# Clear the previous selected View Background and change the background of newly selected View in Onclick - Android

Tags: android, onclick, android-view, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

I want to change the background view when it's pressed (its working). My problem is, If i press the other view (not the same one) in the list, i want to set my background to Black of the newly selected view and change the background to White of the previous selected view. Here is my Implementation

```
for(final TotalPlayers player :     this.playerData){
    final ArrayList<View> addedPlayerViews1 = getPlayerView(player);
    dropPlayersListView.addView(addedPlayerViews1.get(0));
    addedPlayerViews1.get(0).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    boolean highlight = false;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!highlight)
        {
            addedPlayerViews1.get(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            highlight=true;
        }
        else {
            addedPlayerViews1.get(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            highlight=false;
         }

       }
     });        
   }
}
```

Comment: why are you doing this?? you are adding one view at arraylist . what is the purpose of that?

Answer (score 0):

```
addedPlayerViews1.get(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            addedPlayerViews1.get(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            highlight=false;

    }
});
```

I assumed that you can get the other view by get(1).

The problem of your code was you only handled the onClick event of your view where you want to change the background. but you also need to handle the onClick of other view too.

Comment: Hi Stine, Thank you for the quick reply. But i am not getting the other view by addedPlayerViews1.get(1). Its looping through an array.

Comment: you need to set the onClickListener to that other view too.. I used get(1) just for an example